# Nodejs Get get results printed to the browsers, but it prints to console log

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to print the result to res.json() but its not printing to the web

```
app.get('/valiate_email/:email', async (req, res, next) =>{
     await validateEmail(req.params.email, (result)=>{
         
          console.log(result);

          res.json({"result":result});

    });
});
```

console.log(result) prints just like i want it

```
[
  email: 'arererew-ewdog@mail.ru',
  validated: true,
  validationResult: {
    regex: { valid: true },
    typo: { valid: true },
    disposable: { valid: true },
    mx: { valid: true },
    smtp: { valid: true }
  }
]
```

but res.json({"result":result}); comes to the broswer like this {"result":[]}

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: What is the code snippet of `validateEmail` function? Is it a library function? If so, then what is the name of that library?

Comment: Sorry, here it is I added. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You have added you code to answer, please remove from there and update the question

Comment: Try this `res.send().json(result)`

Comment: I did that, now its giving me 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: i tried to paste into the additional code it gives me an error saying too much code in the context of the question. :(